# What is the exact mathematical formulation of calculation of Mutual Information and F-Score in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics

I would like to know the exact mathematical formulation of the two metrics Mutual Information (MI) and F-score used in this [example in scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_f_test_vs_mi.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-f-test-vs-mi-py). The documentation states only the following:

- for MI: referring to couple of papers and the wikipedia page without details.
- for F-score:

1. The cross correlation between each regressor and the target is computed using r_regression as:
   [image]
2. It is converted to an F score and then to a p-value.

Comment: Are you talking about categorical or numeric features and categorical or numeric target?

Comment: In any case, have you checked the source code? [_mutual_info.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/364c77e04/sklearn/feature_selection/_mutual_info.py#L391)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found what I want the in the source code!

Comment: @okamal I'm glad I could help. I posted this as an answer and would appreciate if you accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculations for Mutual Information (MI) and the F-score in `scikit-learn` may vary based on whether the variables are categorical or numeric.

You might find it helpful to look directly at the source code:

- For **Mutual Information**:

  - For **classification** tasks: [`mutual_info_classif`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d/sklearn/feature_selection/_mutual_info.py#L405)
  - For **regression** tasks: [`mutual_info_regression`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d/sklearn/feature_selection/_mutual_info.py#L315)
- For the **F-score**: [`f_regression`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d/sklearn/feature_selection/_univariate_selection.py#L348)

I hope this helps.